# Bootstrap4 NavBar for Mobile bug

Tags: html, mobile, bootstrap-4, navbar

Im going to code a Website with Bootstrap. There my navbar works well for desktop. But when Im using this website for a mobile device The button with all links doesnt work. [a pic for more accurate description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzLdY.png)

Here is my html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse bg-faded py-md-3">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand nav-link display-5" href="#">Pomics</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSuportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link display-5" href="index.html">Startseite<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Diskussionen</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Umfragen</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quellensammlung</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Anmelden</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Could sb help me with my problem?
thank you in advance!
lg bttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct target name for the toggler...

Currently you have: `data-target="#navbarNav"`, but there is no element with `id="navbarNav"` so nothing will happen when the button is clicked.

Change the `id="navbarSuportedContent"` to `id="navbarNav"`.